# #1111 - Invalid use of group function error in stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllData() 
BEGIN 
DECLARE execPrice DOUBLE;
    SET execPrice = sum(LastQty * LastPx) / sum(LastQty);
select 
    execPrice as avgExedPrc,
    sum((LastQty * LimitPrice)) / sum(LastQty) as avgOrdPrc,
```

unable to use the variable execPrice.
could someone please help.

Comment: where is your `select` clause?

Answer (score 0):

`sum()` is only used in a query, as it sums 1 or more rows.

Here you don't even have anything to be summed:

```
SET execPrice = sum(LastQty * LastPx) / sum(LastQty);
```

Change it to

```
SET execPrice = LastQty * LastPx / LastQty;
```

Comment: we are using this equation in the stored procedure in many place. so we want to use the variable instead of equation.

Comment: Erm, yes, you can do so. Have I said something that doesn't make you think so? Have you tried my answer? Are there still problems?